# Scroll to a position inside a div with React hooks

Tags: react-hooks, scroll

I'm implementing a list of items that is scrollable and that the user can filter with a search field. When the user empties the field I want to scroll back to the position the user was at when they started the search. I'm using React with hooks but cannot get the element to scroll when the search field state changes. I was able to call the scroll function at other places in the code and it worked, but I don't understand why it doesn't work with the useEffect hook.

This is my useEffect that should run when the field is empty:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (!tableWrapperRef.current) {
      return
    }
    if (!filterText) {
      tableWrapperRef.current.scrollTo({ top: scrollPosition })
    }
  }, [tableWrapperRef, filterText])
```

Should I use something other than useEffect?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add a `setTimeout` without any actual time value. For some reason scrolling inside a useEffect doesn't work without it.